# How to change date type in template? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Greeting.

How to change the format in a template. I use a date picker.

I want to display the format example: 12/15/2019

The current state of how he displays it to me example: Mon Dec 30 2019 22:10:40 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Look my code for date:

```
startDate: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startDate = new Date();
    this.startDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() + 1);
}

template:

              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
                  <input  [matDatepicker]="date" [(ngModel)]="startDate" name="startDate"  matInput   placeholder="Izaberite datum isporuke"   >
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker touchUi #date></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

 <p> Order for {{ startDate }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to to do this:

```
this.startDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() + 1);
this.startDate = this.startDate.toLocaleDateString();
```

That converts the format to what you are after.
But you can use various other options as well, such as using Moment.js or adding a pipe that does the date formatting and calling it in the template when you output the date:

```
<p>order for {{ startDate || formatDate }}</p>
```

A pipe is a nice, clean way to handle that kind of thing if you're doing it a lot or the formatting is more complex and you want to handle it all in one place.

EDIT:

I forgot it was being used as the variable for a date picker so to keep it as a Date type you can't use the `toLocaleDateString` in the component.

Output it in the HTML as

```
<p>order for {{ startDate.toLocaleDateString() }}</p>
```

There you still have the Date object in the component as the correct type. Which is a good example of why pipes are useful :)

Comment: This is work but [ts] Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
When I start to build for production i will got error and i can't building app

Comment: another important thing. When you do this first example of how you write a I lost date in an input type I was set.